# Why is Ruby's string.sub() not greedy?

Tags: regex, ruby

How is the following behavior explained?  (running with Ruby 2.4.2)

```
> "hello\r\n".sub(/e*/, "")
 => "hello\r\n" 

> "hello\r\n".sub(/h*/, "")
 => "ello\r\n" 

> "hello\r\n".sub(/e+/, "")
 => "hllo\r\n" 

> "hello\r\n".sub(/(\r|\n)*/, "")
 => "hello\r\n" 

> "hello\r\n".sub(/(\r|\n)+/, "")
 => "hello"
```

For (1), how the `e` is not matched and replaced by `""`, versus (2) the `h` is?  And then when it is `e+`, then it is matched?  (so `e*` is "non-greedy"? Isn't it by default greedy?)

It is similar for the 4th and 5th cases. I know I can use `gsub`, but how is the behavior of `sub` explained?

Comment: Have you read the docs? For me, it seems to explain it pretty well: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-sub):

> Returns a copy of str with the first occurrence of pattern replaced by the second argument.

The keyword here is "first". If I [match `hello\r\n` against `e*`](https://regex101.com/r/sF55t3/1), what's my first match gonna be? A 0-width match at position 0, isn't it? Yes, `e*` will greedily match the `e` in `hello`, but that's not the first match. It needs to match all the 0-width matches before that first.

On the other hand, `e+` can't match any 0-width matches, so the first match is the match you expect.

For `h*`, the first match is the letter `h` because it is the first letter in the word! There are no 0-width matches before it.

The same logic applies to the other cases as well.

Comment: No, sorry, please disregard the crap I posted above. Everything is perfectly correct.

Comment: "For `h*`, the first match is the letter h because it is the first letter in the word! There are no 0-width matches before it." - You state this as if it was obvious, but actually, for *regular expressions* (the mathematical concept on which `Regexp` is based), there are *infinitely many* empty strings at the beginning, at the end, and in between every character, so it is understandable that one might get confused by the fact that this is not true for `Regexp`s. The main takeaway is, I guess: even though `Regexp` are based on regular expressions and some people even call them "regular

Comment: … expressions", that does by no means mean that they *behave like* regular expressions.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Oh I see. I didn't really study regex the math concept, so that's something new for me. Thanks.

Comment: the "nothing" would be considered a match... nothing has slipped my mind...

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's true... if nothing can be considered to be a match... there are infinitely many matches really, before it can get to `e`... but I guess once it matched nothing, then it advances 1 position anyway: `"hello".scan(/e*/)
 => ["", "e", "", "", "", ""]`

Comment: @JörgWMittag While you're right to correct his assertion about there not being any zero-width matches before the `h`, this is just a mistake he's made, it has nothing to do with a difference between Ruby and classical regular expressions (there _are_ many such differences, but I don't think this is one of them).